# Trying to learn C++20 composable code with CRTP mixins as implementations of interfaces that are checked with concepts

Tags: beginner, c++20, mixins, composition

I am trying to teach myself some composability using CRTP and concepts.
I came up with this simple example and wondered, what I could/should do better there
or, if it is a reasonable starting point?

Godbolt compiler explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/dd3xTfz44

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

// null
struct dummy {};

// composition
template <template <typename> class... mixins>
struct do_compose {
    struct box : public mixins<box>... {};
    using type = box;
};

template <template <typename> class... mixins>
using compose = do_compose<mixins...>::type;

// interface definitions
template <template <typename> class mixin>
concept nameMixin = requires(mixin<dummy> m) {  //
    std::is_same_v<decltype(m.name), std::string>;
};

template <template <typename> class mixin>
concept helloMixin = requires(mixin<dummy> m) {  //
    { m.hello() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

// implementations
template <typename USER>
struct mixin1 {
    std::string name{"Mixin 1"};
};
static_assert(nameMixin<mixin1>);  // interface check

template <typename USER>
struct mixin2 {
    void hello() {
        auto self = static_cast<USER*>(this);
        std::cout << "Hello world, I am " << self->name << std::endl;
    }
};
static_assert(helloMixin<mixin2>);// interface check

// user code
int main() {
    compose<mixin1, mixin2> obj;
    obj.hello();
}
```

output on godbolt.org:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
Hello world, I am Mixin 1
```

Comment: It may *look* reasonable, but whether it *is* reasonable depends on what you are going to use it for. Without a real use case it's very hard to review this code.

Comment: I want to use it for a networking library based on standalone ASIO. Configuration, transport, serialization etc. of server resp. client are mixins. In the moment I'm mostly concerned with the combination of modular implementations with clear interfaces that can be checked in a good way. So - for me it's about composability, maintainability and staying performant.